# When creating a scroll, how should the scroll's cost be handled in-game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

When a Cleric creates a 5th level scroll, the cost is 1,125 gp. But how should PCs roleplay spending money for the scroll's cost?

I know the Pathfinder PRD indicates "a character needs a supply of choice writing materials, the cost of which is subsumed in the cost for scribing the scroll". But subsumed means the cost of writing materials is included in the scroll's price; it doesn't mean it's equal to the price. Thus, if my "choice writing materials" cost 10 gp, what happens to the remaining 1,115 gp when I create a scroll? Does it magically disappear? Is it supposed to be offered as an offering to the Cleric's god?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don’t get a choice in your writing materials: you have to use certain, special materials to make a scroll. The rules are intentionally vague for the purposes of allowing groups leeway in how they describe this, but in the end the sum total of the costs of paper, inks, paints, incense or candles, *whatever*, should equal the stated cost of scribing the scroll. So there is no “rest” to have to figure out.

Offerings to gods/nature also do seem appropriate for divine spellcasters, yes, for what it’s worth. Ultimately it should be worked out between the DM and the player.

Comment: True story: adding the last line of this answer to any answer makes it correct.

Comment: Amusing though corsiKa's comment is, the last line is particularly important in this case because Pathfinder deliberately leaves this detail of magic item creation vague; Whether the cost of a magic item is investigated in depth or just left abstract is a decision each table has to come to an agreement about.